# Excel: Subtracting One Value from the Next Entry in Column

Tags: excel, search, find, dataset, subtraction

I have a set of data that has two columns, one for enumerating entries, and the second for storing a value:

```
1    0.000000000
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   
8   
9    0.664076596
10  
11  
12  
13  
14  
15  
16  
17  
18  
19  
20  
21  
22  
23  
24  
25  
26  
27  
28  
29  
30  
31  
32  
33  
34   0.668394223
```

The values in column 2 are separated by varying numbers of rows throughout my data sheet. I want to subtract each value (Value B) in column 2 by the previous value above it (Value A) (ie 0.664076596 - 0.000000000, and 0.668394223 - 0.664076596 etc.). I want to put these results in the third column and next to Value B. How would I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Use this which will find the last number value in the column before the current row.

```
=IF(B2="","",IFERROR(B2-INDEX($B$1:B1,MATCH(1E+99,$B$1:B1)),B2))
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution but the results column shows the true value it is next to, not the difference. ie column 2: 0.664077 column 3: 0.664077, column 2: 0.668394 column 3: 0.668394. Formula didnt find the difference...

Comment: Then you are getting errors, is your data set like the one I have in the photo?  If not in which cell did you place the first formula and what is the adjusted formula you used?

Comment: No my set is not the same. My "0" data value starts in B24. I did not adjust the formula as I pasted your solution in C2. Do I need to adjust the formula?